# Opencart seo url for view all products page

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart, vqmod

For my opencart site, I'm using a vQmod [show_all_product.xml](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/download&extension_download_id=585874) so that the path `/index.php?route=product/category&path=0` shows all my products on a category page. It's working perfectly, but ideally what I would like to do is use a SEO friendly URL to achieve this, e.g. `/viewall` would give the same page.

I would much appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure **mod_rewrite** is enabled.
Then, also make sure you can use `htaccess` (Apache config -> `AllowOverride All`).

Put this code in your htaccess (assuming it is in root folder, like your `index.php` file)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^viewall$ /index.php?route=product/category&path=0 [L]
```

Comment: @user1258303 You're welcome. Don't forget to validate my answer if it was helpful

Comment: You're better off looking at using/creating a vQmod or Override Engine extension to handle this programatically.